# How to find the native method from the JVM source code?

Tags: java, jvm

I found the ClassLoader invoke some JVM native code, so I tried to check these native code from the JVM source code below, for example I want to check the method defineClass1 ,however I find I failed to get them.
May I how to find the related JVM source code based on the native code invoked from the Java code?

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/log?rev=defineClass1

```
private native Class defineClass0(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len,
                                  ProtectionDomain pd);

private native Class defineClass1(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len,
                                  ProtectionDomain pd, String source);

private native Class defineClass2(String name, java.nio.ByteBuffer b,
                                  int off, int len, ProtectionDomain pd,
                                  String source);
```

Comment: There might be multiple versions, i.e. per platform. Just download and fire up a text searching tool. Looking up the methods in the commit logs is very likely to fail, I wouldn't expect them to contain that kind of information.  - However, I'd like to ask you: what do you want to do? Why are you interested in the native code?

Comment: @Thomas , I want to study the JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JNI implementation of the above methods is in JDK repository, not in HotSpot,  see [src/share/native/java/lang/ClassLoader.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/774f11d707e0/src/share/native/java/lang/ClassLoader.c#l90)

However, these methods eventually call back to JVM through HotSpot-specific 
`JVM_DefineClassWithSource` API. The implementation of this JVM function is in HotSpot repository, see [src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/fb8ea28efb05/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l1049)

Comment: this is exactly what I needed answer, thank you so much.